# Perl grep-like one-liner with regex match condition and assignment?

Tags: perl

Say I have this file:

```bash
cat > testfile.txt <<'EOF'
test1line
test23line
test456line
EOF
```

Now, I want to use `perl` in a "grep like" manner (a one-liner expression/command with file argument, which dumps output to terminal/stdout), such that I match all of the numbers in the above lines, and I make them into zero-padded three digit representation. So, I tried this to check if matching generally works:

```bash
perl -nE '/(.*test)(\d+)(line.*)/ && print "$1 - $2 -$3\n";' testfile.txt
#test - 1 -line
#test - 23 -line
#test - 456 -line
```

Well, that works; so now, I was thinking, I'll just call `sprintf` to format, assign that to a variable, and print that variable instead, and I'm done; unfortunately, my attempt there failed:

```bash
perl -nE '/(.*test)(\d+)(line.*)/ && $b = sprintf("%03d", $2); print "$1 - $b -$3\n";' testfile.txt
#Can't modify logical and (&&) in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near ");"
#Can't modify pattern match (m//) in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near ");"
#Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Ok, so something went wrong there. As far as I can tell from the error messages, apparently mixing logical AND (`&&`) and assignments like in the above one-liner do not work.

So, how can I have a Perl one-liner where a regex-condition is checked; and if match is detected, a series of commands are executed, which may involve one or more assignments, and conclude with a `print`?

---

EDIT: found an invocation that works:

```bash
perl -nE '/(.*test)(\d+)(line.*)/ && printf("$1%03d$3\n", $2);' testfile.txt
#test001line
#test023line
#test456line
```

... but I'd still like to know how to do the same via `sprintf` and assignment to variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence issue.

```perl
/.../ && $b = ...;
```

means

```perl
( /.../ && $b ) = ...;
```

You could use

```perl
/.../ && ( $b = ... );
```

```perl
/.../ && do { $b = ...; };
```

```perl
/.../ and $b = ...;
```

```perl
$b = ... if /.../;
```

But there's a second problem. You call `print` unconditionally.

```bash
perl -ne'printf "%s-%03d-%s\n", $1, $2, $3 if /(.*test)(\d+)(line.*)/'
```